# Why when I print an integer using an immediate value it works fine, but if I try to print a label containing a integer It does not print anything?

Tags: assembly, mips

Is my first time trying to code something in MIPS language.
I tried printing using a label, expecting it to behave like a variable, but it doesn't print it. Why is this happening?

printing an immediate works:

```
    .text
    .globl  main

main:

    # Print label 
    li  $v0,1       # print_int syscall code = 1
    la  $a0, 24     
    syscall

    li  $v0,10      # exit
    syscall
```

printing it like this using a label wont work, there is no output:

```
    .text
    .globl  main

main:

    # Print label 
    li  $v0,1       # print_int syscall code = 1
    la  $a0, mylabel    
    syscall

    li  $v0,10      # exit
    syscall

    # Start .data segment 
    .data
mylabel:    .word 12
```

My logic is that the address of "mylabel" contains the number 12 , and has a size of 1 word which is the usual size for an integer in MIPS. but there must be something I'm missing there?. thanks all.

Comment: Basically a duplicate (answered in comments): [In MIPS 32 Assembly, why is "la" used to print strings but "lw" used to print integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67326630)

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that `mylabel` is just some number that refers to a memory location. Printing the address probably doesn't make much sense other than for debugging purposes.

The `la` instruction loads an address into a register, so when you do `la  $a0, mylabel`, you're saying "load the integer adddress corresponding to `mylabel` into `$a0`".

The print int service that's associated with syscall 1 is going to emit whatever number is in the `$a0` register. It does not dereference this memory location.

If you want to get the contents of `mylabel`, you'll need to load the memory into a register using the `lw` instruction ("load word" rather than "load address"):

```
.text
.globl main

main:
    li $v0 1
    lw $a0 mylabel
    syscall # => 12

    li $v0 10
    syscall

.data

mylabel: .word 12
```

Going a step further, let's say you had two elements in the `mylabel` array. If you want to load the second element, you can use `la` and `lw` with an offset:

```
.text
.globl main

main:
    li $v0 1
    la $t0 mylabel
    lw $a0 4($t0) # 4 byte offset from mylabel
    syscall # => 13

    li $v0 10
    syscall

.data

mylabel: .word 12 13
```

Comment: Most MIPS assemblers even allow `lw` as a pseudo-instruction, like `lw  $a0, 4+label`.  (But for teaching purposes, yes it's probably better to show getting the address explicitly, then loading the value, so that's more of a fun-fact than a criticism).  Also, for style I'd recommend commas between operands, like `li $v0, 1` although apparently MARS accepts this.